# How to POST a MultiPart/Form data from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, http, curl, multipartform-data

I'm currently developing a VB.NET program in Visual Studio 2017, and while I'm reasonably competent with most aspects of VB.NET, this one has me completely stumped. 
The program needs to POST multipart/form data to Mixcloud (which is like Soundcloud but for radio programmes). After some research, all I have found are dead ends. In Mixcloud's API for uploading (found [here](https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/#uploads)), they give a CURL example on how to do it. Would anyone have an idea on how to implement this in VB.NET? Many thanks in advance for any help available.

Here is their example:

```
curl -F mp3=@upload.mp3 \
 -F "name=API Upload" \
 -F "tags-0-tag=Test" \
 -F "tags-1-tag=API" \
 -F "sections-0-chapter=Introduction" \
 -F "sections-0-start_time=0" \
 -F "sections-1-artist=Artist Name" \
 -F "sections-1-song=Song Title" \
 -F "sections-1-start_time=10" \
 -F "description=My test upload" \
 https://api.mixcloud.com//upload/?access_token=INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```

(The "sections" are essentially markers that are shown on the player to highlight different points of a radio show - just to provide some context!)

Comment: Unfortunately translating code is too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to make an attempt of your own first, then ask when you bump into a more specific problem. Start by looking up what cURL's `-F` command does (for instance on [its documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)), then look for the respective way to do so with a `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: If that is how POST request looks like you just need to imitate it. Of course, with your data, so instead of those placeholder value eg "my test upload" you input your data and send it.